# Django messages framework - lack of i18n by default

Tags: django, django-messages

By default django messages framework does not localize it's messages correctly.
For example in admin interface

[image]

As you can see all other things in admin panel are localized. The translation file [exists](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3e01aab5335394201701710d7fcd67f523878c5b/django/contrib/admin/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/django.po). Here is my settings.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    ...
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru' # I've tried 'ru-RU'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Moscow'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

How to fix this? Thanks in advance. I have django version 3.0.6. This error also is absent in django 1.8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was a breaking change from [django/django@42b9a23](https://github.com/django/django/commit/42b9a23267f14be39b9b00958e18d5746783208e) (Django 3.0+) that only updated the French translations.

You can patch `DjangoTranslation.gettext` to handle the smart quotes.

```py
def _patch_gettext():
    from django.utils.translation.trans_real import DjangoTranslation
    _gettext = DjangoTranslation.gettext

    def gettext(self, message):
        text = _gettext(self, message)
        if text is message and '“' in message:
            new_message = message.replace('“', '"').replace('”', '"')
            new_text = _gettext(self, new_message)
            if new_text is not new_message:
                return new_text
        return text

    DjangoTranslation.gettext = gettext
```

## About patching

Subclass `AppConfig` in **mysite/apps.py**:

```py
from django.apps import AppConfig


class MySiteAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'mysite'

    def ready(self):
        _patch_gettext()
```

Put the dotted path to that subclass in `INSTALLED_APPS` in **mysite/settings.py**:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'mysite.apps.MySiteAppConfig',
]
```

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/applications/#configuring-applications

Comment: Wow thanks for this investigations and clean and understandable answer!.